# Using conditional multiple strategies in one guard

Tags: nestjs, passport.js

I'm using NestJs+Fastify+Passport.
I have global guard with accessStrategy by default and I need to make it use different strategies if decorator @SetAccessRight used.

So, this is my decorator

```js
import { SetMetadata } from '@nestjs/common';
import type { AccessRight } from '@enums';

const SetAccessRight = (request: AccessRight): MethodDecorator => SetMetadata('accessRight', request);
export default SetAccessRight;
```

and enum:

```js
export enum AccessRight {
  public = 'public',
  refresh = 'refresh',
  confirm = 'confirm',
  reset = 'reset',
}
```

It's working like this:

```js
@Get('refresh')
@SetAccessRight(AccessRight.refresh)
refresh() {}
```

Now about my guard:

```js
import { ExecutionContext, Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AccessRight } from '@enums';
import { JwtConfirmStrategy } from '../strategies/jwt-confirm.strategy';
import { JwtResetStrategy } from '../strategies/jwt-reset.strategy';
import { JwtRefreshStrategy } from '../strategies/jwt-refresh.strategy';

@Injectable()
export class JwtGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt-access') {
  constructor(
    private reflector: Reflector,
    private confirmStrategy: JwtConfirmStrategy,
    private resetStrategy: JwtResetStrategy,
    private refreshStrategy: JwtRefreshStrategy,
  ) {
    super();
  }

  handleRequest(err: any, user: any, info: any, context: any, status: any): any {
    if (info) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException(info.toString());
    }

    return super.handleRequest(err, user, info, context, status);
  }

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    const accessRight = this.reflector.get<AccessRight>('accessRight', context.getHandler());

    switch (accessRight) {
      case AccessRight.public:
        return true;
      case AccessRight.confirm:
        // ??? use confirm strategy ???
        break;
      case AccessRight.refresh:
        // ??? use refresh strategy ???
        return true;
    }
    return super.canActivate(context);
  }
}
```

So JwtGuard should use 'jwt-access' strategy by default if endpoint don't use @SetAccessRight() decorator, and different strategy if it use decorator.
I don't know how to make it right, because it's not just chaining strategies, it's conditional use and I couldn't find any information on how to do it anywhere, as if I'm the first person in the world trying to do that.

I've tried to execute strategy this way:

```js
this.refreshStrategy.authenticate(context.switchToHttp().getRequest());
```

but I'm getting this error:

```js
/.../node_modules/passport-jwt/lib/strategy.js:111
                            return self.error(err);
                                        ^
TypeError: self.error is not a function
    at verified (/.../node_modules/passport-jwt/lib/strategy.js:111:41)
    at JwtRefreshStrategy.callback [as _verify] (/.../node_modules/@nestjs/passport/dist/passport/passport.strategy.js:20:21)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it can be implemented like this:

```js
class RefreshGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt-refresh') {}
class ConfirmGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt-confirm') {}
class ResetGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt-reset') {}
...
canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    const accessRight = this.reflector.get<AccessRight>('accessRight', context.getHandler());

    switch (accessRight) {
      case AccessRight.public:
        return true;
      case AccessRight.confirm:
        return new ConfirmGuard().canActivate(context);
      case AccessRight.refresh:
        return new RefreshGuard().canActivate(context);
      case AccessRight.reset:
        return new ResetGuard().canActivate(context);
      default:
        return super.canActivate(context);
    }
  }
```

Now, you don't have to use `@UseGuards()` decorator on each route, just `@SetAccessRight()`